ASP.NET Core: Is there a way to throw multiple errors in a custom JsonConverter? Or access the ModelState?
I have problem inside a custom JsonConverter that I am potentially catching multiple errors (through attempting to deserialize the JSON, and if it fails, remove the offending propertry and try again) and it looks like based on the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0#error-handling) you are supposed to throw a JsonException inside your custom converter if there are any issues. Yes, you can do that, and then the exception will end up in your ModelState once it gets to processing the endpoint. But it defeats the whole purpose of why I wrote my own converter, to NOT have it fail after one error, but aggregate all errors.
Currently I am forced to wrap my Model inside another class so I can store these errors separately and process later. But then these errors seem to bypass validation even when implementing a custom validate method to check if the deserialization errors are empty (as shown below).
Is there anyway I could stick my collection of errors into the ModelState from the JsonConverter Read method? Or is there a way to throw multiple errors inside the converter without having it fail after the first error?
Without doing something hacky like combining all errors into one error with line breaks in the message. Because I also store which key its associated with not just the string.
Write any custom converter and inside the read method put something like this:
    public override MyWrapperClass<T> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonDocument jsonDoc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        var root = jsonDoc.RootElement;
        var hasFields = root.TryGetProperty("model", out var fields);

        var modeldObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var modelJsonObject = JsonObject.Create(fields);
        var deserializationErrors = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            modeldObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(modelJsonObject, options)!;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            deserializationErrors.Add(ex.Message);
            var keyPropertyName = ExtractJsonKeyFromErrorMessage(ex.Message); //returns the $.[KeyName] part of error message that all JsonExceptions have.
            modelJsonObject.Remove(keyPropertyName);
        }
        //this would be done in recursively until you can deserialize with no errors, just giving a simple example
        try
        {
            modeldObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(modelJsonObject, options)!;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            deserializationErrors.Add(ex.Message);
            var keyPropertyName = ExtractJsonKeyFromErrorMessage(ex.Message); //returns the $.[KeyName] part of error message that all JsonExceptions have.
            modelJsonObject.Remove(keyPropertyName);
        }

        return new MyWrapperClass<T>
        {
            Model = modeldObject!,
            JsonDeserializationErrors = deserializationErrors
        };
    }

With the class:
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyWrapperClassJsonConverter))]
public class MyWrapperClass<T> : IValidatableObject
    where T : class
{
    public required T Model { get; set; }
    public List<string> JsonDeserializationErrors { get; set; } = [];

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach (var deserializationError in JsonDeserializationErrors)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                deserializationError,
                ["_deserializationError"]);
        }
    }
}

But I would rather just not have the wrapper class and push the multiple errors to the ModelState directly.

I still use Newtonsoft.Json and I use the related JsonSchema.NET to validate input and generate a list of errors to fill ModelState - and I only deserialize the JSON if the schema-validation succeeded. YMMV. I don't know what the equivalent in System.Text.Json is - if any.

I'm writing this for a custom separate package, I don't want to include the NewtonSoft.Json library as an additional dependency. But when using it, where do you do that validation? Inside a custom JsonConverter?

This seems like a pattern problem—instead of throwing for each, why don't you have some sort of list object to store the errors in, then throw at the end with the list as a property of the exception?

Please bear with me.. Per my understanding, if we are receiving an invalid JSON response, the sender should check the why it's invalid but not the receiver. Or you just want to have a tool which could find out all the invalid key-value pair?

@TinyWang It's irrelevant, I was just providing some context. I want to be able to send multiple JSON exceptions to the ModelState from a custom JsonConverter. The sender would be the same party as the receiver. I am already finding the invalid keyvaluepair, but I have to store them separately in JsonDeserializationErrors property of Model wrapper class because I can't see any way to pass more than one error up to the ModelState.

Model state represents errors that come from two subsystems: model binding and model validation. So that I'm afraid we need to keep creating custom ModelState validation next...
